# How to add an image field to a blog in Drupal 7 without using the admin toolbar?

Tags: drupal-7

I just started doing work with a website running on Drupal 7 that hosts a number of blogs from different users, and I've been tasked with adding a Image field to the blog content type.  On my local copy of the website, I added an image field to the blog using the admin toolbar.  However, I can't log in as an admin on the development or production servers, but I can edit the code and push it to the servers.  How I might go about doing this?

This is my first experience with Drupal, so I don't really know what I'm doing.

Answer (score 0):

You can't.

There are several options to do this, but you would have to add the field to the content type, or write and install a custom module that adds the field for you. Both would require admin access though.

And I would really recommend you not to change code. Drupal 7 is built around fields, so hardcoding them could result in some very nasty problems breaking the whole thing.

Comment: Okay, thanks. How would I write the module to add the field for me?

Comment: There are many treads about it on http://drupal.stackexchange.com . I'd syggest you start with this one. http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/10749/how-to-add-cck-field-to-a-content-type-programatically-in-drupal-7